# Showing that $U$ is a one-parameter unitary group

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose $U$ is a family of operators acting on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that
$$U(t)f(x) = f(x + t). \tag{1}$$
I would like to show that $U$ forms a one-parameter unitary subgroup, that is for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$U(a+ b) = U(a)U(b) \tag{2}$$
and that $U$ is strongly continuous:
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow t_0} U_tf = U_{t_0}f.$$
Without any further assumptions (such as linearity), how does (1) satisfy (2)? That is, (2) would require $f(x + a +b) = f(x + a)f(x+b)$, but how can we conclude that for any $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Can anyone provide a hint on how to show $U$ is strongly continuous?

Comment: $(U(a+b)f)(x)=f(x+a+b)=(U(b)f)(x+a)=(U(b)U(a)f)(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $U$ is strongly continuous you need to show that for all $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ it holds $\lVert U(t)f-f\rVert_2 \to 0$ as $t\to 0$. Expanding this you can see that what you essentially need to prove is that for every $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ you have
$$\lim_{t\to 0} \int_\mathbb{R} |f(x+t)-f(x)|^2\,dx=0$$

Now, this is a pretty standard fact for $L^p$ spaces, the proof of which can be found online or in analysis textbooks. The standard technique for such problems is to first show what you need for functions that are compactly supported and then for arbitrary functions in $L^2$ by using the fact that any function in $L^2$ can be approximated with compactly supported functions.

**EDIT:** I think you got confused with $(2)$. $U(a)U(b)$ does not stand for multiplication, rather it is equivalent to $U(a) \circ U(b)$, i.e. operator composition. So
$$U(a+b)f(x)=f(x+a+b) = U(a)f(x+b) = U(a)U(b)f(x)$$

Comment: Thank you, I was able to show that part. However it is still not clear to me how $U$ satisfies condition (2).

Comment: @CBBAM I've edited my answer. It's quite common to omit the $\circ$ symbol when we talk about operators but it can be confusing at times.

Comment: Thank you for all your help!